# How to normalize training data for different activation functions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I'm training fully connected neural network to classify MNIST dataset. Input data are square black-and-white images with pixel values in `[0, 255]`.

I've read that for using `sigmoid()` activator one needs to normalize input to be in `[0, 1]` (range of sigmoid).

How to normalize input data for `tanh()` activator? Do I need to rescale it to be in `[-1, 1]` (range of tanh) or it can still be in `[0, 1]`.

Which approach is better and why? What is the general guidance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to use a different normalization for a different activation function. In fact you don't have to normalize the input to be in `[0, 1]` for sigmoid. The range of sigmoid `[0, 1]` is the range of its output. Its range for input (domain) is in fact from minus infinity to positive infinity.

What's more is that your input does not go directly into the sigmoid function so the range of your image input is not the same as the range of input that sigmoid would get. There will be some linear layers in between which change the data range.

The general guidance is to normalize your input to be in `[-1, 1]`. This has nothing to be with the activation function but a general effective measure for back propagation. See [Effective BackProp](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My logic for `[0, 1]` normalization was that each next layer gets as an input output from previous sigmoid layer. That is input for every but first layer in the network is in the output range of the activation function. Which kinda implies that you should do the same for 1st layer.

Comment: @Ribtoks The variances in input data range should be taken care of by the linear operators. It doesn't really matter whether each layer receive the same range of input or not. Another suggestion: Just try it out. Training a MNIST classifier is quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

Normalization lead to a proper behavior of the neural network since it eases the network weights tunning, for this you can either chose a standardization or normalization.

Standardization = (x - mean(x)) / std(x);

Normalization = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min);

Moreover there is a nice research of tanh-estimators by Hampel et al. that seem to be robust in terms of outliers.
They considered the following x_norm = (1/2) * (tanh (0.01 * ((x - mean(x)) / std(x))) + 1)

Tanh-estimators normalization reference can be found at: https://www.cs.ccu.edu.tw/~wylin/BA/Fusion_of_Biometrics_II.ppt